# Why does my token is not being stored after registering a user?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jwt, redux-toolkit

I am dealing with an issue while submitting a register form. The user is created but my token is not being stored into localStorage so it is not redirecting me immediately into the app and instead I have to login.

This is my `RegisterForm.jsx`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector, useDispatch  } from 'react-redux';
import { registerUser } from '../../slices/authSlice';
import FormGroup from '../UI/FormGroup';
import '../../styles/UI/FormGroup.css'

function RegisterForm() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { isAuthenticated, error } = useSelector(state => state.auth)
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    fullname: "",
    birth_date: "",
    gender: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    password2: "",
  });
        
  const onChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value, type, checked } = e.target;
    if (type === "checkbox") {
      if (checked) {
        setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: [...gender, value] });
      } else {
        setFormData({
          ...formData,
          [name]: gender.filter((option) => option !== value),
        });
      }
    } else {
      setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
    }
  }

  const formFields = [
    {
      name: "fullname",
      type: "text",
      placeholder: "Insert Full Name",
      label: "Full Name",
      value: formData.fullname,
      onChange: onChange
    },
    {
      name: "gender",
      type: "radio",
      placeholder: "",
      label: "",
      value: formData.gender,
      onChange: onChange,
      options: ["male", "female"] 
    },
    {
      name: "birth_date",
      type: "date",
      placeholder: "",
      label: "Date of Birth",
      value: formData.birth_date,
      onChange: onChange
    },
    {
      name: "email",
      type: "email",
      placeholder: "Email",
      label: "Email",
      value: formData.email,
      onChange: onChange
    },
    {
      name: "password",
      type: "password",
      placeholder: "Password",
      label: "Password",
      value: formData.password,
      onChange: onChange
    },
    {
      name: "password2",
      type: "password",
      placeholder: "Confirm Password",
      label: "Confirm Password",
      value: formData.password2,
      onChange: onChange
    }
  ]

  const onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(registerUser(formData));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      navigate('/');
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated, navigate]);

  return (
    <form action="" className="form_container" onSubmit={(e) => onSubmitHandler(e)}>
      {formFields.map((field) => (
        <FormGroup key={field.name} {...field} />
      ))}
      <button type="submit">Register</button>
      {error && <p style={{ color: 'red', marginTop: '10px' }} className="error">{error.message}</p>}
    </form>
  )
}

export default RegisterForm
```

And this is my `authSlice.js`

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';
import setAuthToken from '../utils/setAuthToken';

const initialState = {
  access_token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: {},
  isLoading: false,
  error: null,
};

export const loadUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/loadUser',
  async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    if (localStorage.token) {
      setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
    }

    try {
      const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/auth/me');
      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);

export const registerUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/registerUser',
  async (user, { dispatch, rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Accept: 'application/json',
        },
      };
      const body = JSON.stringify(user);
      const res = await axios.post(
        'http://localhost:8000/api/auth/register',
        body,
        config
      );
      dispatch(loadUser(res.data));
      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data.message);
    }
  }
);

export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/loginUser',
  async ({ email, password }, { dispatch, rejectWithValue }) => {
    const body = { email, password };
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
    };
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        'http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login',
        body,
        config
      );
      localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.access_token);
      dispatch(loadUser(res.data));
      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data.message);
    }
  }
);

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    logoutUser: (state) => {
      state.access_token = null;
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
      state.user = null;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(loadUser.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
        state.isAuthenticated = state.access_token ? true : false;
      })
      .addCase(loadUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isAuthenticated = true;
        state.user = action.payload;
        state.error = null;
      })
      .addCase(loadUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isAuthenticated = false;
        state.error = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(registerUser.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(registerUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.access_token = localStorage.setItem(
          'token',
          action.payload.access_token
        );
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isAuthenticated = true;
        state.user = action.payload;
        state.error = null;
      })
      .addCase(registerUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.user = null;
        state.isAuthenticated = false;
        state.error = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(loginUser.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(loginUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.access_token = action.payload.access_token;
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isAuthenticated = true;
        console.log(state.isAuthenticated);
        state.user = action.payload;
        state.error = null;
      })
      .addCase(loginUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.user = null;
        state.isAuthenticated = false;
        state.error = action.payload;
      });
  },
});

export const { logoutUser } = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

For some reason as I register a user the action `registerUser` is fulfilled with a token. I tested that token with the endpoint `"/me"` in postman and it contains the correct user information. But after register is fulfilled, the `loadUser` action is rejected. So it seems it is not loading the token into my localStorage and indeed the localStorage is empty.

This is how I am handling my routes in `App.jsx`

```
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/UI/Home';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/UI/Navbar';
import Footer from './components/UI/Footer';
import Register from './Pages/Register';
import Login from './Pages/Login';
import Profile from './Pages/Profile';
import Dashboard from './Pages/Dashboard';
import PrivateRoute from './components/Routing/PrivateRoute';
import useAuth from './customHooks/useAuth';

function App() {
  const { isAuthenticated, loading } = useAuth();

  if (loading) {
    return <h1 className='title loader'>Loading...</h1>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className='content-container'>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
          <Route path='/profile' element={<PrivateRoute><Profile /></PrivateRoute>} />
          <Route path='/register' element={<Register />} />
          <Route path="/" element={isAuthenticated ? <Dashboard /> : <Home />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is my custom hook `useAuth.js`

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { loadUser } from '../slices/authSlice';

const useAuth = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadAuthenticatedUser = async () => {
      await dispatch(loadUser(localStorage.getItem('token')));
      setLoading(false);
    };

    loadAuthenticatedUser();
  }, [dispatch]);

  return { isAuthenticated, loading };
};

export default useAuth;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `registerUser` action should set the token into localStorage just like the `loginUser` action does. You may also want to wait and unwrap the returned Promise from the `loadUser` action so the doesn't get any intermediate state of a "half-logged-in" user, e.g. they are authenticated but the user data has yet to be loaded.

```js
export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/loginUser',
  async ({ email, password }, { dispatch, rejectWithValue }) => {
    const body = { email, password };
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
    };
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        'http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login',
        body,
        config
      );
      localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.access_token); // <-- sets token!
      await dispatch(loadUser()).unwrap(); // <-- await loading user data
      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data.message);
    }
  }
);
```

```js
export const registerUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/registerUser',
  async (user, { dispatch, rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Accept: 'application/json',
        },
      };
      const body = JSON.stringify(user);
      const res = await axios.post(
        'http://localhost:8000/api/auth/register',
        body,
        config
      );
      localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.access_token); // <-- set token too!
      await dispatch(loadUser()).unwrap(); // <-- await loading user data
      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data.message);
    }
  }
);
```